# Sort and filter a list based on elements from a second list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, the first one contains peoples' names, with each person associated with various characters, for example numbers, letters, e.g.:

```
listNameAge = ['alain_90xx', 'fred_10y', 'george_50', 'julia_10l','alain_10_aa', 'fred_90', 'julia_50', 'george_10s', 'alain_50', 'fred_50', 'julia_90']
```

The second one contains the name of the person:

```
listName = ['fred', 'julia', 'alain', 'george']
```

Using the second list, I would like to associate a third list to the first one, such that each name in the first list is associated with its index position in the second one, i.e.:

```
thirdlist = [2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

The name and characters are separated by an underscore, but the character can be of any sort. I could loop over the elements of `listNameAge`, separate the name of the persons from the rest of the characters using a `.split('_')` on the string,   find which name it is and find its index in `listName` using a second loop.

I was however wondering if there is a simpler way to do this, i.e. avoid using loop and use only a comprehension list?

Comment: Note that a list comprehension (which is what I assume you meant) still involves a loop.

Comment: Hi, yes, I meant list comprehension. What I would to avoid are "for loops"

Comment: And list comprehensions **still involve for loops**. I'd recommend you use a dictionary `{name: index}` to avoid the poor time complexity of the answers so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take each item in `listNameAge`, then `split` on `'_'`, get the first part of the split, then use `index` to find it in the second list.

```
>>> [listName.index(i.split('_')[0]) for i in listNameAge]
[2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Hei, thanks that worked perfectly and it is quite clear. My lists are not so long, so the time complexity is not really a problem. .

Answer (score 3):

While you can do this with a one-liner, I think that, for efficiency, it wold pay to build a dictionary:

```
namePos = dict((name, i) for (i, name) in enumerate(listName))
>>> [namePos[n.split('_')[0]] for n in listNameAge]
[2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

The (expected) running time of *this* code, is *Θ(m + n)* where *m* is the length of the first list, and *n* the length of the other one.

Answer (score 2):

For this question in specific, I would recommend you use a loop just for clarity. However, if you must use a list comprehension, you can do that essentially the same way:

```
thirdlist = [listName.index(x[:x.find('_')]) for x in listNameAge]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
thirdList = [listName.index(string.split("_")[0]) for string in listNameAge]
```

It is a list comprehension composed of `listName.index(string.split("_")[0]` where `string` is defined for each item in `listNameAge`.  `string.split("_")[0]` is the string from the beginning of the string to the first underscore, so `listName.index(string.split("_")[0]` is the first occurrence of that in `listName`.

Comment: Can you add some explanation?

Comment: @Will: I have added some.  If anything could be potentially unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (This popped up in the review queue. Answers with only code tend to get flagged automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this , check whenever the `listNameAge` appears in `listName` :

```
for x in listNameAge:
    for y in listName:
        if y in x:
            thirdList.append(listName.index(y))
```

result :

```
[2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend against using `.index()` as its complexity is `O(n)` and makes the overall complexity of this operation `O(mn)` where `m` and `n` are sizes of the lists.

Here's a fast one liner using generators:

```
map(lambda (x,y): y[x[:x.find('_')]],izip(listNameAge, repeat(dict(izip(listName, count())))))
```

More readable version would be (as Ami has shown):

```
nameMap = dict(izip(listName, xrange(len(listName))))
thirdList = map(lambda x: nameMap[x[:x.find('_')]],listNameAge)
```